# Return NSDictionary data from popup tableview

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary, tableview

I have a popup tableview (ViewController2) appearing when I click a button on ViewController1.  Then when I select a row in the table, I want those values to be sent back to ViewController1.  I have a NSDictionary set up.  It works fine in a regular navigation controller, but trying to do it with dismissModalViewControllerAnimated, so the tableview drops back down, and the data is appearing in the first view.

This is similar to this question here I think: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/39995-return-data-dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated.html

Here is my code:

ViewController1.h:

```
@protocol ViewController1Delegate;
@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController <ViewController2Delegate> {
    id <ViewController1Delegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ViewController1Delegate> delegate;
@end
@protocol ViewController1Delegate
- (void)viewController1DidFinish:(ViewController1 *)controller;
@end
```

ViewController1.m:

```
-(void)buttonGoToViewController2 {
    ViewController2 *controller = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

//  this controller.delegate = self causes it to crash if i have it uncommented for some reason...
//  controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

ViewController2.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(searching) {
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
        NSDictionary *selectedCountry = [self.copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        ViewController1 *dvController = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil andDictionary: selectedCountry];
        NSLog(@"selected hit this %@",selectedCountry);
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
        [dvController release];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
    else {
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        ViewController1 *dvController = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil andDictionary: dictionary];
        NSLog(@"normal hit this %@",dictionary);
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
        [dvController release];     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController2 code you are creating a new ViewController1 object and giving it your NSDictionary.  When you dismiss ViewController2 you go back to the *original* ViewController1, which never went anywhere and was never sent the NSDictionary. You need to provide ViewController2 with access to the ViewController1 object that presented it (I suggest doing it via a delegate pattern) in order to set the NSDictionary there.

Comment: So in my ViewController2 didSelectRowAtIndexPath, would I have something like this?

 `ViewController1Delegate *appDelegate = (ViewController1Delegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 NSString *nodeText = [[listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"station"];
 NSString *passThis = [appDelegate nodeText];`
 
And then in my ViewController1, I have something like this?

 `ViewController1Delegate *appDelegate = (ViewController1Delegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 PassedString = [appDelegate passThis];`

Comment: No, nothing nearly that complicated.  Check out a tutorial on delegates and protocols like this one: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html